# TypeError: _any() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'where'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read the file using pandas but it is showing me a type error. I am not able to discern why. Can someone help me?
Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


#prepare the files
df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/Boston.csv") # for doing modifications
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/Boston.csv") # for doing modifications

File "/Users/nikhiladiga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
low_memory=_c_parser_defaults["low_memory"],

File "/Users/nikhiladiga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
iterator = kwds.get("iterator", False)

File "/Users/nikhiladiga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1148, in read
names : iterable of names

File "/Users/nikhiladiga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 435, in **init**
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}

File "/Users/nikhiladiga/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 233, in init_dict
datelike_vals = maybe_infer_to_datetimelike(values)

TypeError: _any() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'where'

Comment: please post traceback also.

Comment: Hi Pygirl, have edited the code with the traceback. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that `read_csv` method has troubles parsing your file without any other indications.

Try using additional keywords arguments such as `sep`, `usecols`, etc.

Refer to documentation for more: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: I tried using sep=',' and usecols=[1,2,3] but its still not working

Comment: There are other arguments you could try, in particular related to parsing dates (as the last lines of the traceback seem to indicate a problem there), I suggest you check the docs using the provided link.